# shared_from_this has empty _M_weak_this even after ownership by std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, shared-ptr

I'm storing a class (let's call it `A`) in an `std::vector` using C++ smart pointers (so the vector sigature is `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
  void doWork();
  std::shared_ptr<A> getSharedRef();
};

void A::doWork() { std::cout << "Working..." << std::endl; }

std::shared_ptr<A> A::getSharedRef() { return shared_from_this(); }

class AManager {
  static std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> aList;

public:
  static void init(); // safety because statics
  static void doLotsOfWork();
  static std::shared_ptr<A> createA();
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> AManager::aList;

void AManager::init() { aList = std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>>{}; }

void AManager::doLotsOfWork() {
  for (auto a : aList) {
    a->doWork();
  }
}

std::shared_ptr<A> AManager::createA() {
  std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>();

  aList.push_back(a);
  return a->getSharedRef(); // <----- EXCEPTION
}

int main() {
  AManager::init();
  AManager::createA();
  return 0;
}
```

For some reason, this throws a `std::bad_weak_ptr`, and upon inspection I notice that `a`, for whatever reason, has an `_M_weak_this` equal to `0x0`, or `NULL`. Since I've already created a valid `std::shared_ptr` referencing the object, it shouldn't be empty.

Furthermore, I know no memory corruption is occurring because `A` (with variables) is completely intact at its address.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your description is pretty good. It would be even better to provide code that reproduces the error exactly. Look into how to create a [mcve]

Comment: The biggest problem with an MCVE in this particular case is the code relies on a lot of moving parts, and I'm not exactly sure what parts are producing the error. I do have a github link for the code in question, but otherwise it would take a few hours to spin up a working example.

Comment: why do you need getsharedref() ? (and not just use shared_from_this() directly?) is it because A inherits privately ? if yes, that could be the problem ...

Comment: @CalmBit, I understand where you're coming from; it's not always easy to create a MCVE, but it is often a necessary step. In addition to making your question very answerable, you may find that you solve the problem yourself along the way (and if not, you'll always learn something). You may also find that you were asking the wrong question (You thought the problem was due to X, but it was really due to Y). Finally, and this may sound ridiculous, but creating an MCVE indicates that you respect the answerer's time and do not expect them to be psychic.

Comment: @AndyG - I'm definitely not expecting anyone here to be psychic! And I do respect your time, albeit I'm slightly burnt from having wasted about 6 hours of mine on this single bug - apologies if I'm coming off a little rough. MCVE will be added as soon as I can find the breakage point.

Comment: What kind of inheritance did you use ? Are you sure, `A` class inherits enable_shared_from_this with public ?

Comment: @CalmBit You're not coming off as rough at all! Very pleasant, actually. I may have gotten carried away trying to mentor you in the ways of the fickle C++ community; it looks like you've been around long enough to know as much.

Comment: Do you mean to have 2 copies of the `shared_ptr<A>`, one being `a` and another one in the vector and then ask for a third one with `a->getSharedRef()` ?

Comment: @rafix07 - yes, A inherits publicly.

Comment: @GuillaumeGranié - I'm looking to create the object, store a `shared_ptr<A>` in the `vector`, and then ask for (and return) another `shared_ptr<A>` referencing the same object. Perhaps I'm misusing smart pointers - they're a little touchy, and I'm a little unsure if I'm going about this in the "correct" way.

Comment: When you `push_back(a)` it effectively creates a copy of it. Afterwards, you have `a` and the `shared_ptr<A>` in the vector that points to the class instance. You could create A in-place  `v.emplace_back(std::make_shared<A>());` (if your shared_ptr vector is `v`) so that only `v` has a pointer to it.

Comment: What version,of vs are you using? _very_ old versions had a bug round here iirc

Comment: @AndyG Alright, MVCE posted. And for the record - not VS, just plain ol' gcc and a text editor with formatting.

Comment: The MCVE needs to be in the question, not on a third-party site (particularly not one that hides its content - is it Javascript-dependent or something?).  Please include your code *in the body of the question* as [ask] requires.  Thanks.

Comment: indeed, you're inheriting privately from enable_shared_from_this... or is it a typo of the mcve ?

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Wow. I am not only as blind as a bat but apparently incapable of double-checking. That's almost ten hours down the drain - I'm really sorry for bothering anyone with this garbage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem appears to be because you are inheriting privately from [`enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this)

`shared_from_this` requires "`enable_shared_from_this<T>` shall be an accessible base class of `T`." (according to [util.smartptr.enab])

By inheriting privately, the base class is not accessible, and so the preconditions are violated. I presume this means undefined behavior. Both Clang and GCC throw an exception.

The solution is to inherit publicly.

```
class A :  public std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    //...
};
```

---

*In C++17 the wording appears to have moved to [util.smartptr.shared.const], but the requirement is basically the same.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this can't be detected at compile time. I believe the problem is that `std::make_shared()` couldn't detect that the class derived from `enable_shared_from_this`, because it was `private`, so the ref counts are in a separate memory block instead of using the members of `enable_shared_from_this`, which is why `shared_from_this()` believes it's wrong and throws.

Since `enable_shared_from_this` is a CRTP, can't the STL library define a dummy public verification method and try calling itself via the CRTP class, causing compilation to fail due to privacy?

Comment: minor correction: the ref counts are in the same spot as usual since it's using `make_shared`, but the internal member `weak_ptr` in `enabled_shared_from_this` isn't getting set because it was private.

Comment: "_It's unfortunate that this can't be detected at compile time_" Then don't rely on this very strange hacked up tool. Have a `weak_ptr` that you initialize yourself. Nothing hidden, magical or just implicit.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I have found a counter-example in my code which invalidates what I originally wrote below. There is another subtlety which can lead to `std::enable_shared_from_this` not being initialized properly which I haven't successfully understood yet.

Even though ~andyg's answer is correct, it isn't always sufficient to make the base class public. I ran into a difficult situation with a nullptr weak_ptr like this and I had to find out the hard way that the class with the public `std::enable_shared_from_this` base class can't be sitting inside an anonymous namespace. Hoping this information can help someone in the future!